# Why is $f-c$ a submersion if $\operatorname{grad \ f}(p) \neq 0$?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $$f \in C^{\infty}(M) = C^{\infty}(M,\mathbb{R})$$ and assume that $\operatorname{grad \ f}(p) \neq 0$ for all $p \in M$. For $c \in \mathbb{R}$, the level set $$N_c := f^{-1}(c)$$ is a submanifold of codimension 1 and $T_pN_c = (\operatorname{grad \ f}(p))^{\perp}$ for all $p \in N_c$.

In the proof of this statement, we use the fact that for the function $g = f-c$, if $\operatorname{grad \ f}(p) \neq 0, \forall p \in M$, then $g = f-c$ is a submersion, i.e. the tangent map $$T_pg: T_pM \to T_{g(p)}\mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R}$$ is surjective for all $p \in M$

But I don´t understand why this follows from the fact that $\operatorname{grad \ f}(p) \neq 0$?

Comment: The gradient *is* the derivative in this case.  So if it isn't $0$, it will be rank $1$ (so, surjective).

Comment: Hm, no, actually, this should be for $v \in T_pM$ we have $$T_pg(v) = \sum_{j =1}^{n} v^i \frac{\partial g}{\partial x^j}(p) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}|_p = \langle \operatorname{grad \ f}(p), v \rangle$$ I believe?

Comment: Small correction, it should be $$\langle \operatorname{grad \ g}(p),v \rangle$$

Comment: So you need only to find one $v$ so that $\langle \operatorname{grad} g (p), v\rangle$ is non-zero: then one can consider $cv$ for all $c\in \mathbb R$ to see that $T_p g$ is surjective.